# How QRectF::adjusted() works

Tags: qt, qt4

My custom graphics item has (0,-60 60x60) boundingRect.
When I adjust the coordinates with

```
rect.adjusted(-5,-5,5,5)
```

new boundingRect returns (-5,-65,70x70).
I read the documentation [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qrectf.html#adjusted) and I think boundingRect should return (-5,-65,65x65)

Do I misunderstand the doc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is in the parameters to the "**adjusted**".

Initial  co-ordinates are (0,-60,60,0) ( since height = 60 & width =60)

when you adjust it with (-5,-5,5,5), the new co-ordinates are (-5,-65,65,5).

So now the **width = 70** and the **height = 70**